# Bus error on Pi 3b+ whenever I try to open chromium-browser

Tags: sd-card, chromium

Does anyone know anything about a bus error? This is always happening when I try to open chromium-browser from the commandline. From the graphical interface, the warning is suppressed, I believe. This is a relatively new install (couple of reboots) on a relatively old SD card. How would I investigate this more? A cursory search of the internet, suggests this is a problem with the sd card, would something like an fsck help and can I quantify this?

Comment: A bus error is not a warning.  It is an error.  If you don't get the error when using the GUI you need to find out the difference between how the GUI starts the program and how you are starting the program.

Comment: No, you misunderstand, when I start it from the gui, nothing ever happens.

Comment: You need to make your question clearer.  All clarifications should be edited into the question.